# Website only redirecting sometimes

Tags: iphone, ios, http, user-agent

There is a web site that is in the process of being taken down. Whenever I try to access it on my computer, it automatically reroutes to the new site; however, if I try to view it on my phone, I can view the entire site perfectly fine.

Using HTTrack, I was able to get some of the websites code

```
<!-- Mirrored from www.pensacolachristiancollege.com/ by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x          [XR&CO'2010], Thu, 04 Apr 2013 08:07:40 GMT -->
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Page has moved</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.pcci.edu/">
<A HREF="http://www.pcci.edu/"><B>Click here...</B></A>
</BODY>
<!-- Created by HTTrack Website Copier/3.46 [XR&CO'2010] -->

<!-- Mirrored from www.pensacolachristiancollege.com/ by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x     [XR&CO'2010], Thu, 04 Apr 2013 08:07:40 GMT -->
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type"  content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
</HTML>
```

Could someone explain why this is happening, and maybe how I could view the site on my computer?
At first I thought I could spoof the user agent string. `Apple-iPhone3C3/1001.523` is what I found for iPhone 4 CDMA with ios 6; however, It still doesn't allow me to view the site.

Comment: This tag is the reason for redirect to the another page. **<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.pcci.edu/">**

Comment: I kind of figured that. But why doesn't it redirect when I am on my iPhone?

Comment: Because in a iPhone browser as safari , This META tag is not supported by Safari.. And your not the only one who asked that.. There is 2 possibility:

1).Make a button to let user refresh the page
2).Use Ajax to be able to update parts of your website
Hope this helps!

Comment: and in this code you have added this one **<A HREF="http://www.pcci.edu/"><B>Click here...</B></A>** . this tag is mentioned in first point. you are manually click here to refresh your page. hope this will be useful for u.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not my website, and I cannot change it. I am merely trying to access it through my computer, either normally or by downloading it